# set the values to Form::select() in kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

my controller is like this

```
$content = View::factory('user/biochemistryTestForm')
                  ->bind('result', $result);
            $this->template->content = $content;
   //here $result is array of Datatbase records
```

**in view**

```
<?php echo Form::select('allvalues', $result,null, null) ?>

this tag generate code to browser like this

<select name="allvalues">
<option value="0">Photo</option>
<option value="1">Kishore</option>
<option value="2">Chandrapal</option>
<option value="3">Framework</option>
</select>
```

i want to set values to this tag programatically

help me

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to set values to this tag programatically"

Comment: i want set values to select tag programatically
like this
`<option value="Photo">Photo</option>
<option value="image">image</option>`

Comment: It would aid me in answering correctly if you could edit the question and add the line where you assign a value to the `$result` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but I'll have a stab at answering regardless.

If you want to set the values of the select options to something other than numeric then you need to assign an array with associative keys to the `$result` variable in the controller.

```
$result = array(
    'photo' => 'Photo',
    'kishore' => 'Kishore',
    'chandrapal' => 'Chandrapal',
    'framework' => 'Framework'
);
```

**EDIT:** I noticed your `$result` variable is assigned an array from the database, you've not posted the code that assigns a value to `$result` so I'm going take a stab in the dark.

You need to add `->as_array('key','value')` to the end of your Database result call in the controller. The *key* will be used as the array key, which will become the select option value and the *value* will be used and the array value which will become the select option label.

**Controller**

```
$results = DB::select('name')
    ->from('things')
    ->execute()
    ->as_array('name', 'name');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya You are right ... now my code is working yaar..
many thanks

Answer (score -1):

if u want set values to the select tag you can use html tag

```
<select name="allvalues">
<option value="Your value">Photo</option>
<option value="Your value">Kishore</option>
<option value="Your value">Chandrapal</option>
<option value="Your value">Framework</option>
</select>
```

directly instead of kohana tag

```
<?php echo Form::select('allvalues', $result,null, null) ?>
```